# How to write a generic function to get the length of an atom list

Tags: c

I have defined structs as follows:

```
typedef struct decls  *Decls;
typedef struct expr   *Expr;
struct decls {
    Decl      first;
    Decls     rest;
};
struct exprs {
    Expr first;
    Exprs rest;
};
```

and I defined a function to get the length of a Decls

```
static int list_length(Decls decls) {
    if (decls) {
        return 1 + list_length(decls->rest);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

How can I make this function generic to get the length of Exprs without defining another copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generic list and store a pointer to object (Expr, or Delc) in the first part and cast first to a pointer to the appropriate type to use it.

```
struct list {
    void *first;
    struct list *rest;
};

static int list_length(struct list *l) {
    if (l) {
        return 1 + list_length(l->rest);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, there are two approaches to "generic" programming: OOP and macros. You can implement a generic function for list length with a macro like the following:

```
#define CREATE_LIST_LENGTH_FUNCTION(prefix, Type)    \
static int prefix##list_length(Type decls) {         \
    if (decls) {                                     \
        return 1 + prefix##list_length(decls->rest); \
    } else {                                         \
        return 0;                                    \
    }                                                \
}
```

and use it to "instantiate" two functions:

```
CREATE_LIST_LENGTH_FUNCTION(decl_, Decls);
CREATE_LIST_LENGTH_FUNCTION(expr_, Exprs);
```

If you prefer OOP like style of generic programming, you can define your list structures with a common prefix. For example:

```
typedef struct listPrefix {
   struct listPrefix *next;
} LP;
```

and your two structures as:

```
struct decls {
    LP   listpart;
    Decl first;
};
struct exprs {
    LP   listpart;
    Expr first;
};
```

then you define length on `struct listPrefix *` as follows:

```
static int list_length(struct listPrefix *l) {
  if (l) {
     return 1 + list_length(l->listPart.next);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

And you can invoke it with casting the input pointer on both lists:

```
list_length((struct listPrefix *) decl_list);
list_length((struct listPrefix *) expr_list);
```

Comment: +1 for the **first** approach. You're missing the `prefix##` on the second list_length.

Comment: I cannot change the definition of exprs which means I could use your LP. Any idea?